# unhide el icono de git en vscode

Tags: git, vscode

Hace unos dias escondi sin querer el icono de git de activity bar y no se como restaurarlo si alguien sabe como desocultarlo seria de gran ayuda su respuesta.Graciias

[image: activity bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas simple es utilizando la combinación de tecla `Ctrl+Shift+G` o con clic derecho sobre la barra y te mostrara las Opciones disponibles en mi caso dice  `Source Control` haces clic para que te marque con con un Check la opción y listo ya tendrías visible el icono.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono perfectamente!!